# How to find something between a String and two dots?

Tags: java, regex

I´m trying to get out some value inside a text with regex.

Text example:

COMISION 002...................50.00........15.060000...............753.00 IVA 21 %

I would like to get: 753.00

I´m using this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.\\.)(.*)(?=IVA 21 %)");
```

The problem is that this regex is outputting:

.................50.00........15.060000...............753.00

So I assume that the first time the engine finds the two dots (..) sets a limit.

What I want and can´t resolve is something like: "find the words "IVA 21 %", then look back and bring me all of the data till you see two dots together"

I´m new in the regex world so any help is appreciate.

Comment: Anything known about the structure of the value before `IVA`? Because if its a decimal number, `\.\.(\d+\.\d+) IVA 21 %$` can be used as a starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture your number:

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?= IVA 21 %)
```

[ReEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO2gY3/1)

In your regex negative lookbehind `(?<=\.\.)` will assert first two dots in the input that are right after `002`.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot man. Could you explain how you achieve it so it´s clear for further modification?

Comment: `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` is a generic regex pattern to capture an integer or decimal number. and `(?=...)` is lookahead that you already in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first group of the following regex.

```
(\d+.\d+) IVA 21 %
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG7xN7/1)